# How make eclipse adc see my phone?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, ddms, adc

I'm trying to run my App on a real hardware phone.

I have the adb installed and I tried to kill-server, then start-server and every time when I write adb devices my device shows up okay.

Then I go to the DDMS in the Eclipse and there also my phone is okay connected and stuff, I can even take screenshot from my display.

But then when I want to run my App, the pop-out (Android Device Chooser) window is empty. There are only Virtual machines there.

I did this on my Windows PC and it worked fine, and I was able to run my App.
I reinstalled Eclipse several times, but with no luck.

Comment: what is the minimun SDK  for the project , target SDK , and the platform of the device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same experience after upgrading my mac to OS X Yosemite. Try enlarging the serial number column in your Android device chooser. That did the trick for me, since the device was apparently only 'hidden'.

Comment: Click and hold the edge of the column with your mouse and drag it to the right. Like you would enlarge a column in excel.